# Should related posts show excerpts?

Tags: interaction-design, design, content

What is the benefit of showing excerpts in related posts vs showing just titles?

Provided that excerpts are normally just 1-3 lines of text, does this really make it more compelling or does it add any value?

Comment: This really depends on the type of related content that will be displayed. If the content is duplicative, there really is no need to show the excerpt. However, if the content is a fuzzy match, you should show the excerpt because it might not be directly apparent how the content is related without it.

Answer (score 1):

Solely based on my opinion, I think there are very few cases where adding the excerpts would be more valuable than just **good** titles alone.

The only great examples of excerpts over titles that I've seen are usually reporting articles like the [New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com), or  [Scientific American](http://www.scientificamerican.com/) or short story forums like [THRESHOLDS](http://blogs.chi.ac.uk/shortstoryforum/). The content is what makes the excerpts valuable and worthwhile.

For most other applications, **great titles** and **great accompanying photos** together should do the trick while also saving you valuable screen space.

Comment: This is what I thought too - mainly because those titles with excerpts (and photos) are front and center, but most related posts I've seen only have titles and photos.